# Property 'clear' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to implement below url code in ionic react app that allows the user to sign on a canvas.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-signature-canvas-example-xevhz?file=/src/App.js

error

> TypeScript error in
> D:/wamp/www/demos/ionictest/myApp/src/pages/Tab3.tsx(14,39):
> Property 'clear' does not exist on type '{}'.  TS2339
>
> ```
>     12 | const sigCanvas = useRef({});
>     13 | 
>   > 14 | const clear = () => sigCanvas.current.clear();
>        |                                       ^
>     15 | 
>     16 | const save = () =>
>     17 |     setImageURL(sigCanvas.current.getTrimmedCanvas().toDataURL("image/png"));
> ```

my code

```
import { IonContent, IonHeader, IonPage, IonTitle, IonToolbar } from '@ionic/react';
import ExploreContainer from '../components/ExploreContainer';
import './Tab3.css';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import SignaturePad from 'react-signature-canvas'
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import "./sigCanvas.css";

const Tab3: React.FC = () => {

const [imageURL, setImageURL] = useState(null);
const sigCanvas = useRef({});

const clear = () => sigCanvas.current.clear();

const save = () =>
    setImageURL(sigCanvas.current.getTrimmedCanvas().toDataURL("image/png"));

  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonHeader>
        <IonToolbar>
          <IonTitle>Tab 3</IonTitle>
        </IonToolbar>
      </IonHeader>
      <IonContent fullscreen>
        <IonHeader collapse="condense">
          <IonToolbar>
            <IonTitle size="large">Tab 3</IonTitle>
          </IonToolbar>
        </IonHeader>
        <SignaturePad
              ref={sigCanvas} 
              canvasProps={{
                className: "signatureCanvas"
              }}
            />
    <button onClick={save}>Save</button>
    <button onClick={clear}>Clear</button>

    <br />
      {/* if our we have a non-null image url we should 
      show an image and pass our imageURL state to it*/}
      {imageURL ? (
        <img
          src={imageURL}
          alt="my signature"
          style={{
            display: "block",
            margin: "0 auto",
            border: "1px solid black",
            width: "150px"
          }}
        />
      ) : null}
           

      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
};

export default Tab3;
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Can you provide steps to replicate the error ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're using typescript, UseRef should have a type

```
const sigCanvas = useRef<any>()
```

Answer (score 1):

As you're using Typescript, you have to provide a type for your ref

```
const sigCanvas = React.useRef<React.MutableRefObject<any>>();
```